# The 'scriptFile' property is set to a file that does not exist. When running azure function locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I get the following error in the console, when trying to run my Azure function written in C# using Visual Studio:

> The 'ReadData' function is in error: Invalid script file name
>   configuration. The 'scriptFile' property is set to a file that does
>   not exist.

Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33870

Comment: Hi, Did the issue is resolved? I am getting the same issue while running the azure function locally.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the issue is closed. You need to run

```sh
npm install

npm start
```

And not "func start" as stated in Azure document

Comment: Running npm start  ends up running  tsc build which resolves the  error

Answer (score 0):

I do not have reputation to write a comment hence posting it as an answer.

Is it possible to share some of the code where you are getting error?
what kind of file are you reading from? is it appsettings or something else?
you can check out [.netcore configuration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to understand the issue better.

Comment: The error occours in an Azure function http trigger I just created. This error shows up in the console when running the function, not in VS.

Comment: @Recusiwe Hi, can you offer more information? like the code of your function?